# What does the last dimension in YOLO output image array correspond to?

Tags: python-3.x, image-processing, yolo

I was reading an article where I found this:

*The first detection is made by the 82nd layer. For the first 81 layers, the image is down sampled by the network, such that the 81st layer has a stride of 32. If we have an image of 416 x 416, the resultant feature map would be of size 13 x 13. One detection is made here using the 1 x 1 detection kernel, giving us a detection feature map of 13 x 13 x **255***

Upon implementing the YOLO algorithm, building the model and passing an image as input to the Conv net, I got a doubt in this snippet:

```
output_vec = model.predict(img)
print([squeeze(a).shape for a in output_vec])
```

> [(13, 13, **255**), (26, 26, **255**), (52, 52, **255**)]

I understand (13, 13); (26, 26); (52, 52) are the image shapes at three different scales but what does 255 correspond to ?

Answer (score 1):

The number of output channels corresponds to the following equation B x (5 + C).

Each point in the output feature map will predict **B** bounding boxes where each bounding box is composed from 5 numbers: 4 for the bounding box prediction and the fifth number for the confidence in this bounding box.
And also the classification confidence for each one of the **C** classes it is trained on.

In case of YOLO v3 which was trained on COCO, B = 3 and C = 80 -> 3*(5 + 80) = 255

Comment: Ohh I got it... Thanks!!